# ¿Cómo mantener el scroll abajo al abrir un chat?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actualmente estoy desarrollando un chat en el cual quiero que al abrir una conversación el scroll se mantenga al final de la conversación, ya que es muy tedioso tener que bajar para ver el último mensaje.

Estoy es lo que llevo:

```js
$("#html, body").stop().animate({
  scrollTop: $("#search2").offset().top
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="search2" class="direct-chat-messages" style="overflow: scroll; height: 400px;">

  <div class="direct-chat-msg">
    <div class="direct-chat-info clearfix">
      <span class="direct-chat-name pull-left">user</span>
      <span class="direct-chat-timestamp pull-right">date</span>
    </div>

    <img class="direct-chat-img" src="img/default.jpg">

    <div class="direct-chat-text">
      aqui va el mensaje
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Pero no logro que el scroll se posicione al final de la conversación. ¿Cómo podría hacer eso?

Comment: Realmente, el código compartido no tiene mucho que ver con la pregunta en sí. Deberías editar la pregunta para añadir más información (¿Qué has investigado?) así como algo más relevante en cuanto a código (¿Qué has intentado para mover el scroll abajo? ¿con qué errores/dificultades te estás encontrando?). Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

con jQuery podes hacerlo usando [scrollTop()](https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Al momento de añadir un nuevo mensaje, tenes que setear `scrollTop` al alto total (`scrollHeight`), espero que quede claro, arme un pequeño ejemplo para que puedas verlo en práctica!

```js
$('#conjQuery').on('click',function()
{
    //Le agrego otro ''Mensaje''
    $('#divu').append('<div class="chatMessage"></div>');
    //Fijo el scroll al fondo
    $('#divu').scrollTop( $('#divu').prop('scrollHeight') );            
});

$('#animado').on('click',function()
{
    //Le agrego otro ''Mensaje''
    $('#divu').append('<div class="chatMessage"></div>');
    //Fijo el scroll al fondo usando añadiendo una animación (animate)
    $("#divu").animate({ scrollTop: $('#divu').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
});

function sinjQuery()
{
    //Obtengo el div
    var e = document.getElementById('divu');
    //Le añado otro mensaje
    e.innerHTML += '<div class="chatMessage"></div>';
    //Llevo el scroll al fondo
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("divu");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
}
```

```css
#divu
{
    max-height: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: antiquewhite;            
    margin: 10px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.chatMessage
{
    height: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divu">
    <div class="chatMessage"></div>
    <div class="chatMessage"></div>
    <div class="chatMessage"></div>
    <div class="chatMessage"></div>
    <div class="chatMessage"></div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="conjQuery">Con jQuery</button>
<button type="button" id="animado">Con jQuery Animado</button>
<button type="button" onclick="sinjQuery()" id="sinjQuery">Sin jQuery</button>
```

Saludos

Comment: gracias amigo, es justo lo que buscaba, saludos.